# Getting item properties from a dropdown in Vue.Js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am struggling to output one of the object properties (SKU) from an item selected in a dropdown box. I have tried a few variants with no success.

How can I access one of the object properties if I don't display it (use an expression) in the dropdown. In essence, how do I show the SKU of an item outside of the dropdown?

```
<select v-model="selected">
<option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">
    {{ option.text }}
</option>
</select>
<span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>
<p>The SKU of your selected item is {{ selected.sku }}</p>

new Vue({
el: '...',
data: {
    selected: 'A',
    options: [
    { text: 'One', value: 'A', sku:'TT5' },
    { text: 'Two', value: 'B', sku:'BB8' },
    { text: 'Three', value: 'C', sku:'AA9' }
    ]
}
})
```

Comment: do you want to show the `sku` property and you can't?

Comment: Yes, I need to show the the text property to the customer in the dropdown and a summary in the span. Plus leave the "option.value" in the v-bind so it can be passed to my backend.  But I also want to display the SKU to the customer in a paragraph outside of the select box.

Comment: the values are unique ?

Comment: i edited my answer by adding some details that fit to your use case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to bind the whole object to your `option` element as follows :

```
<option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option">
```

by this way you could access its properties like :

```
  <span>Selected: {{ selected.value }}</span>
  <p>The SKU of your selected item is {{ selected.sku }}</p>
```

Since you need the value property to be passed to the backend you could use a computed property to get the selected the object based on the selected value :

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedVal: 'A',

    options: [{
        text: 'One',
        value: 'A',
        sku: 'TT5'
      },
      {
        text: 'Two',
        value: 'B',
        sku: 'BB8'
      },
      {
        text: 'Three',
        value: 'C',
        sku: 'AA9'
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    selected() {

      return this.options.find(op => {
        return op.value == this.selectedVal
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selectedVal">
    <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">
      {{ option.text }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>
  <p>The SKU of your selected item is {{ selected.sku }}</p>

</div>
```

Comment: You were quicker than me :)  I was working on a fiddle which used the same solution: http://jsfiddle.net/vwszfyd7/

Comment: This is looking good, I'm trying to adapt this code to my personal project and it breaks. Could you help in getting this fiddle to work? whilst leaving the v-bind:value="item.id" in place http://jsfiddle.net/2k7m3h8a/  - As soon as I try and access any of the objects properties(lastprice.sku) it breaks...

Comment: you should give a default value for `products` property like `products:'A'`